# WKWebView HTTP Authentication Username/Password Input

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My app has an embedded WKWebView that we use to show custom user content served from the users organization.  A few organizations are using HTTP authentication (NTLM) so I am working on supporting this.  I've implemented the necessary delegate function (`webView didReceive: completionHandler:)` and create a UIAlertController with two text fields to allow the user to input their username and password.  Functionally, this works and allows the users to log in to their organizations site.

However, because I'm creating the alert controller in my app, usernames and passwords are saved and suggested using the apps associated domain. While technically this makes sense, it is confusing for our users to be logging in to *their* website but seeing a password suggestion coming from *our* domain.

1. I haven't found any way to get the WKWebView to display its own username and password prompt. I've considered trying to inject some javascript to show the prompt, but I'm far from a javascript expert and I'm concerned about causing issues with existing javascript on our customers sites (and I don't know if it will still use the app domain anyway). Edit - tested this, the app domain is still used.
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/ seems to say that there's no way to use a different url.

Is there anyway for the username and password to be saved using the url that is being loaded in the web view instead of the apps associated domain?